# OmniSharp does not work for NUnit project

Tags: .net-core, visual-studio-code, nunit, omnisharp

I have a .NET Core solution with a few projects in it. Everything worked fine until I added an NUnit test project today. OmniSharp seems to totally ignore this new project and the following things do not work:

- error checking
- IntelliSense

Basically, when editing C# code in the NUnit project, I do not get any "help" from the editor. VS Code becomes just a text editor.

Why is that? I have the "C#" extension installed. I checked this on both Windows and Linux. The same behavior is on both systems.

I created the NUnit project using `dotnet new nunit --framework netcoreapp3.1`.

//EDIT
Here's a csproje of my NUnit project:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <IsPackable>false</IsPackable>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="NUnit" Version="3.12.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="NUnit3TestAdapter" Version="3.16.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="16.5.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Moq" Version="4.14.7" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\..\MyProject\MyProject.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\..\MyOtherProject\MyOtherProject.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: Could you provide log information of the `OmniSharp`? It lies int the output window. Also, check if the .Net Core 3.1 SDK is installed in your system. Do you see OmniSharp server icon in the status bar of the VS Code?

Comment: @AfsharMohebi I checked the logs. There is nothing suspicious there. It's logging the same set of information for each one of my projects (Loading Porject, Adding Project, Update Project). There are no errors, nor warnings. Yeah, I see the "fire" icon there. Yes, I have .NET Core 3.1 SDK installed. I am able to work with all other projects, other than my NUnit one (and they are all .NET Core 3.1).

Comment: Can you add a copy of your csproj file to this question? I don't use OmniSharp - but this is a little strange, as an NUnit project created with dotnet new is very similar to any other normal project.

Comment: @Chris I added the csproj

Comment: @Loreno - Thanks...I'm afraid there's nothing in there that looks much out of the ordinary though. Sorry, not sure!